# PHP photo uploader to MySQL and separate folder

Tags: php, mysql, image-uploading

I'm sure I'm doing something silly but I've checked and re-checked this. This is my photo uploader, meant to save the photo file itself to a folder (named "reccs"), and then save the name of the photo to a row in my DB. The DB part works perfectly, but my photo isn't showing up in the folder.
It displays no errors and appears to be working (I get the "success" message). Ack!

Code is below. Thanks for ANY insight.

```
$link = mysql_pconnect($host, $username, $password);
$db = mysql_select_db ($dbname);

$target = "reccs/";
$target = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name']);
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

mysql_query("UPDATE login SET recc = '$pic' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['username']."'");

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

echo "The file has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
 }
else {

echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

Comment: Note that the sql is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Be sure to call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$_FILES['photo']['name']`. In the long run, consider moving to a newer MySQL API like PDO or MySQLi, supporting prepared statements.

Comment: do you have write permission on target folder?

Answer (score 0):

Should reccs have a forward slash in front of it?  It would seem the mysql update query would be better inside the if statement , after  you know the move_upload_file was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
if(move_uploaded_file($pic, $target))
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your server setup you may have to set $target to be an absolute path and not relative. At least it should be absolute to your home dir, so if reccs is a dir in your root site directory then set $target to /reccs/file.name.

The reason for this is that files are uploaded by defualt to /tmp, which is at the root (OS) level, not the hosted level, so paths relative to /tmp are generally meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

saving photo with same name is very bad practice. I will suggest you to do below before uploading the foto.

- extract name and extension.
- now check that extension is valid or not. if valid then go further
- first trim and then clear all multiple spaces with single spaces.
- now lowercase filename and change all space with `_` and append timestamp with filename.
- remove all special characters (  `', " , \ etc` )
- now add filename with that extension .

then store into database